# How to build login page using cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, autologin, login-page

I'm looking for a short tutorial about creating a login page for a website using cookies.

Each user has a `username` and a `password`.

Should I save both the `username` and the `password` in the cookies ? or just the `username` may be enough ?

Can a malicious user steal somehow these cookies and pass the authorization ?

Comment: cookies? Cookies are in client side which is public to client computer. So it is inappropriate to store username and password. I think you better understand the login process. Moreover, what kind of language are you using in server side?

Comment: @Alex: Server side language is PHP. Do you know a good tutorial for creating a login page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store the password in the cookie. If you store just a username, your system is basically completely unsecure. Remember that the client has complete control over the contents of cookies it sends to the server. It can send any username it wants. You should create an authorization token for the specific session (probably with an expiration time associated with it) and store that in the cookie. To prevent tampering with the cookie, you should sign (and encrypt) it on the server and validate the signature.

That said, doing that correctly is not an easy task. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the authentication mechanisms provided by your platform.

Comment: What do you mean by `Use the authentication mechanisms provided by your platform` ? I'm building a website from scratch...

Comment: @Misha: You say that you're using PHP. Instead of implementing your own authentication system from scratch look for some already existing class like:   http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.authentication.auth.intro.php For a simple tutorial about authentication in PHP, see http://insanesecurity.info/blog/8-tips-for-a-secure-login-scriptadmin-panel

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do authentication in PHP. Just google one
http://www.developertutorials.com/scripts/script-details/307067.php

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store you user's passwords in a database, and keep obfuscate them in some way. PHP has a built-in function called md5().

Here's a guide on php.net to help you through.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

I'f you're having trouble grasping these concepts, then I'd recommend working through a php framework. My framework of choice is cakePHP, which makes stuff like authentication a breeze (another top framework is Code Igniter).